# LXML library in PHP?

Tags: php, class, lxml

Is anyone find the class for LXML in PHP. I have no idea about python.

If anyone find the class or library or tutorials, please share with me

Thanks,
Nithish

Comment: I don't think LXML exists in PHP, but there are various XML powerful libraries that should satisfy every need. Which aspect/functionality do you need exactly?

Comment: find this url http://techchorus.net/web-scraping-lxml and many people saying that posting url makes the question invalid is it so?

Answer (score 3):

[lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) *is a Pythonic binding for the libxml2 and libxslt libraries*. There is no exact equivalent that offers the same API in PHP. But most [XML extensions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php), like [DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) or [XMLReader](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) or [XSL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.xsl.php) are based on libxml or libsxlt.

Here is a good overview about the available extensions:

- http://devzone.zend.com/article/1713